# .htaccess redirect root to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in my .htaccess script...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /decco.php
```

Which works perfectly when I type anything like:

```
http://local--decco:8888/abc
```

However, it won't re-direct:

```
http://local--decco:8888 or http://local--decco:8888/
```

How do I modify so that the bare url re-points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a separate rule for landing page because 2 `RewriteCond` will only allow non-file, non-directory requests:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ /decco.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /decco.php [L]
```